# AppendTo property for dynamic dialog

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

For ConfirmDialog there is a property - appendTo [image]

Using this property we can append dialog to any element. I don't see such property for DynamicDialog.

Is there any way to append DynamicDialog to some element, not to body?

Answer (score 0):

Based on dialogservice impl, appendTo is not possible, as you can see below, dialog service appends component by default to the body.:

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dynamicdialog/dialogservice.ts